# Include external javascript file in a nuxt.js page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a relatively simple question.

I am trying to implement [the widget from this codepen](https://codepen.io/saurabhdaware/pen/NWWbOvv) in Nuxt.js.

Here's my code, which works fine if I use RAW HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <dev-widget data-username="saurabhdaware"></dev-widget>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dev-widget@1.0.3/dist/card.component.mjs" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But when I try to include this dev widget in my nuxt.js project, in one of my pages, it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">

    <div>
        <dev-widget data-username="saurabhdaware"></dev-widget>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  layout: "default",
};
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/dev-widget@1.0.3/dist/card.component.mjs" type="module"></script>
```

I keep getting an error:

```
Unknown custom element: < dev-widget >
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add your script in `nuxt.config.js`. Here is how it should look like

```html
export default {
    mode: 'universal',
    /*
     ** Headers of the page
     */
    head: {
        title: 'Your title',
        meta: [{
                charset: 'utf-8'
            },
            {
                name: 'viewport',
                content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
            }
        ],

        link: [
            {
                rel: 'stylesheet',
                href: 'css/mystyles.css'
            }
        ],

        script: [
            {
                type: 'module',
                src: 'https://unpkg.com/dev-widget@1.0.3/dist/card.component.js'
            }
        ]
    },
    /*
     ** Customize the progress-bar color
     */
    loading: {
        color: '#fff'
    },
    /*
     ** Global CSS
     */
    css: [],
    /*
     ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
     */
    plugins: [],
    /*
     ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
     */
    buildModules: [],
    /*
     ** Nuxt.js modules
     */
    modules: [],
    /*
     ** Build configuration
     */
    build: {}
}
```

Answer (score 32):

**Adding as globally**

Navigate to the nuxt.config.js file.
It adds the script tag to all pages in your Nuxt app.

```
export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      {
        src: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
      },
    ],
  }
  // other config goes here
}
```

If you want to add a script tag before closing the `</body>` instead of `<head>` tag, you can do it by adding a `body: true`.

```
script: [
  {
    src: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
    body: true,
  },
```

You can also add async, cross-origin attributes to a script tag like this.

```
script: [
  {
    src: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
    async: true,
    crossorigin: "anonymous"
  },
],
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<script data-n-head="ssr" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
crossorigin="anonymous" async=""></script>
```

**Adding to particular page**

```
<script>
  export default {
    head() {
      return {
        script: [
          {
            src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'
          }
        ],
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Note:**
If you want to add a local js file, place it in a root `static` folder and add it as follows.

```
  export default {
    head() {
      return {
        script: [
          {
             src: '/js/jquery.min.js'
          }
        ],
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

@kiyuku1 's answer would work, but here's the complete solution that would work if we want to include a js (or mjs) file in ONE nuxt.js page only, instead of globally:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">

    <div>
        <dev-widget data-username="saurabhdaware"></dev-widget>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  layout: "default",

  head: {
    script: [
      {
        type: 'module',
        src: 'https://unpkg.com/dev-widget@1.0.3/dist/card.component.mjs'
      }
    ]
  },

};
</script>
```

Comment: This approach will definitely work, but you will run into issues if the external script loads something in you want to work with in Nuxt. Then there's a race condition between your Nuxt (Vue) code running before the external file has been fetched and processed by your browser.

Comment: @beporter Could you tell more about this? I have a script that loads correctly if I start from / and then browse to the page the uses the script. If I load the page directly, the script is not loaded

Answer (score 1):

With nuxt 3.0.0-rc.6 it is:

```json
meta: { 
  script: [
    { src: "https://path.to/your.js" }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the clue in your answer: "Unknown custom element: < dev-widget >".

Register dev-widget component.

For more details: 
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2877

Comment: How do I include the external script file, though?