# NuxtJS add external script component not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to embed a script from an external JS, according to the documentation and this post ([Include external javascript file in a nuxt.js page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59015259/include-external-javascript-file-in-a-nuxt-js-page)) I have something like the following...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <blocksurvey-widget>
      some details
    </blocksurvey-widget>
  </div>
</template>


export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      {
        type: "module",
        src: "https://blocksurvey.io/assets/js/blocksurvey-widget.js",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

I am wondering why this is not working and throws the [Vue-warn] error:

```
Unknown custom element: <blocksurvey-widget> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I believe the script is appended to the head, and I think I need to register the component, but I had the impression this would be working normally once the script has been added. Do I have find some way to add the `<blocksurvey-widget>` component?

Comment: Can you add a little more information? What do you mean this isn’t working— is the script not added to the document? Is it added, but not working how you expect? Is the blocksurvey-widget component registered? etc.

Comment: Is https://blocksurvey.io/assets/js/blocksurvey-widget.js a vue component? if YES you need also to register it at components:{} inside export default function

Comment: The script is added, but the component does not seem to be registered, I suspect I need to include some sort of component?

Comment: I believe I need to register the component, but I am not too sure how to go about doing so. It should be adding some sort of component name? but i had the assumption it should work given the script appended into the head.

Comment: I would suggest making the `blocksurvey-widget` a local js file and placing it in an assets folder. Then in your Vue file import it: `import { BlockSurveyWidget } from 'path-to-assets/blocksurvey-widget.js'; Then you can register `BlockSurveyWidget` in the script tag components: {} as suggested by gijoe.