# Including external script in vue.js template nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i try this solution to use external js but did't work

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <script
      type="application/javascript"
      defer
      src="/assets/javascript/jquery.flexslider-min.js"
    ></script>
  </div>
</template>
```

the error shown

> GET http://localhost:3000/assets/javascript/jquery.flexslider-min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59015259/include-external-javascript-file-in-a-nuxt-js-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning to use some NPM packages, the way to go is [Nuxt plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins).
If you're more into loading 3rd party scripts, the approach explained here is the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585

By the look of your jQuery file, you will probably be interesting by this article: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-load-third-party-scripts-in-nuxt-js/

But if you can, try to either use NPM packages or look for packages in the Vue ecosystem rather than using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

When you use vue or nuxt, the proper way to use external packages is by installing them on your projects using npm or yarn or another package manager.

Comment: thank you i try to put  a file to static folder then it work.